# Vaadin 8: How to update a label value on a modal form from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, vaadin8

I am using vaadin 8, and I need to update a label value on a modal.

In the listing below, a label value is inside a `while(true)` cycle being executed from another `Thread`:

```java
      modal.show();
        modal.getUI().access(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while(true) {
                        sleep(1000)
                        ....
                        break_condition;
                        break;
                        }
                        modal.getLabel().setValue("xxxx")
                    }
        });
```

During the process, the screen will freeze and the modal windows appears at the end with the label value modified. Is it possible to do without freezing the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution...

```
class TaskCycle implements Runnable {

    MyModal modal;

    public TaskCycle(MyModal modal){
      this.modal = modal
    }

        @Override
        public void run() {
           while(true) {
             sleep(1000)
              ....
             break_condition;
             break;
           }
           modal.getLabel().setValue("xxxx");
           modal.getLabel().getUI().push();
        }    
    }


MyModal modal = new MyModal();
modal.show();

TaskCycle r = new TaskCycle (modal);    
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
```

In general, this solution works well but needs of the configuration of a "vaadin server-push" (see the officical documentation).

Unfortunately I am using Liferay 7 and the push server (of vaadin 8) does not work.

This solution in my case is not the best, because the modal is updated with the new values (provided by the thread), only if you perform a "resize" of the browser window/tab.

In order to "simulate" the resize it is possible to insert the function:

```
setPollInterval(1000);
UIEvents.PollListener poll = new UIEvents.PollListener(){

            @Override
            public void poll(UIEvents.PollEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Poll interval start!!!!!");
            }
        };
UI.getCurrent().addPollListener(poll);
```

to remove listener:

```
UI.getCurrent().removePollListener(poll);
```

this is a good workaround for all users that can't use the push() function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to relax the while loop execution introducing a sleep. This could avoid the screen to freeze:

```
Thread.sleep(50);
```

Comment: 1 second of sleep seems to much. Did you tried with 50 milliseconds as on my answer? If yes and this didn't solved I think it should be better for you to share whole code to help community to identify the issue

Comment: same with 50 millisecond....is hard to export the code it is on a remote VM...

Comment: i have also used a thread where run the while(true) cycle but, how update the value of a modal from a thread ?

Comment: Using the thread, the cycle while (true) does not freeze the windows...the problem is how to access to the modal's objects

Comment: no it does not  work...but I have found the solution using the thread